# ¿Por que Android me detiene el servicio que arranca junto SO Android?

Tags: android, servicio

Estoy Implementando un servicio que arranca cuando el sistema termina de iniciarse, lo estuve probando en un dispositivo real(Motorola G6) y si lo arranca al iniciar, pero a los segundos me lo destruye.

El servicio es un ciclo que se ejecuta indefinidamente haciendo peticiones GET a un servidor atravez de Volley y me manda una notificacion en caso de que encuentre algun registro nuevo en una BD. Al principio si que funciona, pero vuelvo a intentar agregar un registro a la BD y ya el servicio es destruido por el SO.

Cabe aclarar que el servicio funciona perfectamente cuando esta siempre activo, cuando lo abro manualmente desde la app.

```
public class ReceiverBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;

    Intent i = new Intent(context, CheckNotificacion.class);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(i);
    } else {
        context.startService(i);
    }

    Log.i("Autostart", "started");
}
```

}

El servicio:

```
public class CheckNotificacion extends Service implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener{

private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

public CheckNotificacion() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    String url = "https://paginaweb.com/get_notifications.php";

                    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("usuario");

                                ArrayList<Noticia> noticias = new ArrayList<>();

                                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int id = jsonObject.optInt("id");
                                    String tipo = jsonObject.optString("tipo");
                                    String titulo = jsonObject.optString("titulo");
                                    String descripcionCorta = jsonObject.optString("descripcion_corta");
                                    String descripcionLarga = jsonObject.optString("descripcion_larga");
                                    String link = jsonObject.optString("link");

                                    String input = jsonObject.optString("fecha");
                                    DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                                    Date date = inputFormatter.parse(input);

                                    DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                    String fecha = outputFormatter.format(date); // Output : 01/20/2012

                                    Noticia noticia = new Noticia(id, tipo, titulo, descripcionCorta, descripcionLarga, link, fecha);
                                    noticias.add(noticia);
                                }

                                revisarNotificaciones(noticias);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                    Thread.sleep((1000*15));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void lanzarNotificacion(Noticia noticia) {
    //Manda una notificacion al usuario

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Random r = new Random();
    int notificacionID = r.nextInt(80000);
    int notificationID = notificacionID;
    String channelID = "my_channel_01";

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "name";

        String description = "description";

        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, name, importance);

        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.enableLights(true);

        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID);
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    if(!noticia.getLink().equals("")) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(noticia.getLink());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    }
    else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeFragment.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    }

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_dos);
    builder.setTicker(noticia.getTitulo());
    builder.setContentTitle(noticia.getTitulo());
    builder.setContentText(noticia.getDescripcionCorta());
    builder.setChannelId(channelID);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, builder.build());
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
}

private void revisarNotificaciones(ArrayList<Noticia> noticias) {
    //Revisamos si las notificaciones recibidas ya fueron vistas
    for(int i = 0; i < noticias.size(); i++) {
        Noticia n = noticias.get(i);
        if(!Preferencias.existeNotificacion(n.getId(), getApplicationContext())) {
            lanzarNotificacion(n);
            Preferencias.agregarNotificacion(n.getId(), getApplicationContext());
            Log.e("LOL", "Lanzamos notificacion "+n.getTitulo());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("usuario");

        ArrayList<Noticia> noticias = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            int id = jsonObject.optInt("id");
            String tipo = jsonObject.optString("tipo");
            String titulo = jsonObject.optString("titulo");
            String descripcionCorta = jsonObject.optString("descripcion_corta");
            String descripcionLarga = jsonObject.optString("descripcion_larga");
            String link = jsonObject.optString("link");

            String input = jsonObject.optString("fecha");
            DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = inputFormatter.parse(input);

            DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String fecha = outputFormatter.format(date); // Output : 01/20/2012

            Noticia noticia = new Noticia(id, tipo, titulo, descripcionCorta, descripcionLarga, link, fecha);
            noticias.add(noticia);
        }

        revisarNotificaciones(noticias);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return this.getName();
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver
        android:name=".ReceiverBoot"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".CheckNotificacion"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Bienvenida"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
</application>
```

Comment: No es propiamente el error por el servicio, podría ser la petición ¿Que muestra en el LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que comentas, probablemente estés administrando mal tu servicio, esto se debe a las restricciones que impone Android. Puedes revisar la documentación donde se describe a más detalle el funcionamiento:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es_419

Estos son dos de los 3 tipos de Servicio disponibles

**Primer plano**

> Un servicio en primer plano realiza una operación que el usuario puede notar. Por ejemplo, una aplicación de audio usa un servicio en primer plano para reproducir una pista de audio. Los servicios en primer plano deben mostrar una notificación. Estos servicios continúan ejecutándose incluso si el usuario deja de interactuar con la aplicación.

**Segundo plano**

> Un servicio en segundo plano realiza una operación que el usuario no nota directamente. Por ejemplo, si una aplicación usa un servicio para comprimir su almacenamiento, suele tratarse de un servicio en segundo plano.
>   **Nota:** Si tu aplicación está orientada al nivel de API 26 o un nivel superior, el sistema impone restricciones en la ejecución de servicios en segundo plano cuando la aplicación misma no se encuentra en primer plano. La mayoría de las veces, es mejor que tu aplicación use una tarea programada.

[Aquí](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html?hl=es_419) puedes revisar las restricciones que impone Android en las ejecuciones en segundo plano.

Basado en la tarea que ejecuta tu servicio, es la implementación que debes hacer en él para que el SO no lo destruya

Para que un servicio corra sin que el SO lo destruya, debes mostrar una notificación de la siguiente manera:

```java
public class MyService extends Service {

    /**
    ...
    */

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        App.dataComponent.inject(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(this));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Y ésta es la clase para generar la notificación a ser mostrada por el servicio:

```java
public class NotificationsUtils {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public static Notification getNotification(Context mContext) {
        MessagesUtils messagesUtils = new MessagesUtils(mContext);
        String title = mContext.getString(R.string.app_name);
        String body = messagesUtils.getMessage(Constants.TEXT_005_KEY);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(mContext));
        return mBuilder.build();
    }

    private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context mContext) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, SplashActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        return stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static void updateNotification(Context mContext) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(mContext));
    }
}
```

De esta forma, debería correr tu servicio sin ser destruido por Android.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero recuerda, hay que agregar una respuesta que ayude a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, esto puede ser la teoría pero sería bueno ayudar a indicar en su código cual podría ser el problema, revisar [ask], saludos.